# Java time to SQL

Tags: java, sql, time

I have a SQL table which contains a column called 'joindate'. I need to enter a value in it, and it has to be an integer. An example of a value in this column is 1374966278, which is 07-27-2013.

How would I generate such a number using Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle convert Date to Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432662/oracle-convert-date-to-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

Use current epoch milliseconds from `System.currentTimeMillis()` divided by 1000:

```
int seconds = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

Although the `long` result of the fivusion will fit in an `int` variable without loss, the compiler doesn't know this; that's why we need the explicit cast.