# Oracle convert Date to Number

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to  convert date to number in oracle 11g .

The date is stored in (12/03/2013 12:23:00).

I want to convert this to Number(The date corresponding number value).
As in java we convert date to long .

I want the same to be done here .

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2013, 05, 23, 0, 0, 0);

    Date date = c.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date is  " + date);
    long longDate = date.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date as long :" + longDate);
    Date d = new Date(longDate);
    System.out.println("Converted Date :" + d);*
```

The Output is :

**Date is  Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 SGT 2013

Date as long :1371916800981

Converted Date :Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 SGT 2013**

Now I want to store value as 1371916800981

Comment: An example of the output would help.

Comment: Good for you.  There are many ways to represent a date as a number.  Please be specific.

Comment: I have added  code . Like Wise I have date in column and want to convert to number as we convert date to Long in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that the long data type that you want is something like the number of seconds or milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

To get this requires just a bit of arithmetic:

```
select (to_date(s1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -
        to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       ) *24*60*60
from (select '12/03/2013 12:23:00' as s1 from dual
     ) t
```

I note that your result is using the current time stamp.  This might include milliseconds which this constant date format doesn't include.

Comment: I want as seconds . not in milliseconds .

Comment: @muthukumar . . . I removed the `*1000`.

Comment: Gordon Linoff.Thanks I will test and reply back.

Comment: I get this error. What is the problem                         00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 55

Comment: The code in the answer was copied directly from a working SQL Fiddle (at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8).

Comment: Do you know the same for SQL Server 
Gordon Linoff

Comment: It is the same logic, you just have to use `convert()` to convert the string to a datetime. Then use `datediff(second, . . . )` for the difference in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a help of RAW data type:

```
SELECT 
  s1,
  to_number(TO_CHAR(s1,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) as s2,
  utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s1) as d1,
  utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s2) as d2,
  round(utl_raw.cast_to_number(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s1)),20) as s1,
  round(utl_raw.cast_to_number(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s2)),20) as s2,
  utl_raw.cast_to_number(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s1)) - utl_raw.cast_to_number(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s2)) as s1_s2_diff
FROM 
( select 
    sysdate as s1, 
    sysdate-1/24/60/60 as s2 
  from dual );
```

Output:

```
S1                  S2      
------------------- --------------
2014.03.16 11:14:16 20140316111416               

D1                                     D2
-------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
323031342E30332E31362031313A31343A3136 323031342E30332E31362031313A31343A3135

S1_1                                   S2_1    
-------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
-53524955535055524769525243,5249435247 -53524955535055524769525243,5249435248

SDIFF     
------------    
0,0000000001
```